# Visual Basic 2010Help

Tags: vb.net, geometry, pi

I need help with a visual basic assignment if any of you guys want to help. 

I am taking an introductory course in programming using visual basic. This project consists of creating a building calculator to determine the material cost to build a circular rail. I need to create an app that allows the user to enter both the diameter of a circle and the price of railing material per linear foot. It should calculate and display the circumference of the circle and the total price of the railing material needed. A constant value for PI 3.141593 should be used. I am stuck trying to create a pseudocode. Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

First consider your inputs and outputs, this will make your pseudocode MUCH easier

### Inputs:

- diameter
- priceOfRailing

### Outputs:

- circumference
- totalPrice

Now all your code needs to do is take those inputs and turn it into those outputs!

### Hints:

- circumference = PI * diameter
- totalPrice = priceOfRailing * circumference

Comment: I never got a chance to say thank you. Thank you.